# matrix analysis and rank of matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I'm trying to prove that if $V(A) \cap N(A)=0$ , where A is a $n \times n$ matrix and $V(A)$ denote the range (column space) and $N(A)$ is the kernel (null space) of $A$, then there exists a non-singular matrix $B$ such that $A^2=BA$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  When posting a question, please be specific about what you do and do not understand, and let us know what you have tried.  This helps people gauge their responses and shows that you're meeting us half way in making an effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

By Your assumptions You have a direct sum decomposition $\mathbb{R}^n=V(A)\oplus N(A)$, i.e. for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there are unique $x_V,x_N$ in $V(A),N(A)$ respectively such that $x=x_V+x_N$.

Now define the linear map $B$ by $Bx=B(x_V+x_N)=Ax_V+x_N$.
Then

$BAx=BA(x_V+x_N)\underbrace{=}_{x_N\in N(A)}BAx_V\underbrace{=}_{Ax_V\in V(A)}AAx_V=A^2x_V \underbrace {=}_{x_N\in N(A^2)}A^2(x_V+x_N)=A^2x$

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

And $Bx=Ax_V+x_N=0$ implies $x_N=A(-x_V)\in N(A)\cap V(A)$ so $x_N=0$ and therefore $Ax_V=0$, i.e. $x_V\in V(A)\cap N(A)$, which means $x_V=0$.

Altogether it follows $x=0$, thus $B$ is non-singular.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That sounds correct.

Comment: @Peter Melech Good proof! But I think that you must point out the existence of $B$.

Comment: @Hoping_VN Thanks. I think $B$, can be just defined in this way using the uniqueness of the representation in the direct sum decomposition. It´s obviously linear.

Answer (score 0):

*Method 1*: somehow similar to @PeterMelech. Set 
$$
B=A\cdot AA^++(I-AA^+)
$$
where $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition).

1. $BA=A^2$ follows immediately from the definition of $A^+$.
2. $Bx=0$ implies $x=0$ as

$$
Bx=0\ \Rightarrow \ \underbrace{A\cdot AA^+x+(I-AA^+)x}_{\text{orthogonal vectors}}=0\ \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
A\cdot AA^+x=0,\\
(I-AA^+)x=0,
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\underbrace{AA^+x}_{\in V\cap N}=0,\\
(I-AA^+)x=0,
\end{cases}
\ \Rightarrow \ x=0.
$$

---

*Method 2*: via Jordan normal form.

Lemma: $\text{Im}(A)\cap\ker(A)=\{0\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\ker(A)=\ker(A^2)$.

*Proof:* $\ker(A)\subset\ker(A^2)$ always and $\ker(A^2)\subset\ker(A)$ by
$$
A^2x=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad Ax\in\ker(A)\cap\text{Im}(A)=\{0\}.\qquad\square
$$
Consider two cases:

1. If $A$ is nonsingular then $B=A$, done.
2. If $A$ is singular. It is equivalent to proving the statement for $J_A$ = the Jordan form of $A$. Since by Lemma $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$, the Jordan blocks of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda=0$ are diagonal, i.e
   $$
   J_A=\left[\matrix{J_1 & 0\\0 & 0}\right]
   $$
   where $J_1$ is nonsingular (corresponds to nonzero eigenvalues of $A$.) Then to get $J_A^2=BJ_A$ we take
   $$
   B=\left[\matrix{J_1 & 0\\0 & I}\right].
   $$

---

*Method 3*: apply the following lemma to $L=(A^2)^T$ and $M=A^T$.

Lemma: Given $m\times n$ matrices $L$ and $M$
$$
\text{Im}(L)=\text{Im}(M)\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad\exists\text{ nonsingular } B: L=MB.
$$
*Proof*: $\Leftarrow$ trivial.

$\Rightarrow$ Permuting if necessary the columns of $L$ and $M$ we can think that the first $r=\text{rank}(L)=\text{rank}(M)$ columns (the blocks $L_1$ and $M_1$ below) are the basis of the image, i.e.
$$
LP_1=\tilde L=[L_1\ L_2],\qquad MP_2=\tilde M=[M_1\ M_2].
$$
By the assumption we have that the columns of $L_1$, $L_2$ and $M_2$ are linear combinations of the columns of $M_1$, i.e.

1. $\exists$ $r\times r$ nonsingular $B_1$ such that $L_1=M_1B_1$.
2. $\exists$ $r\times (n-r)$ matrix $B_2$ such that $L_2=M_1B_2$.
3. $\exists$ $r\times (n-r)$ matrix $B_3$ such that $M_2=M_1B_3$ $\Rightarrow$ $[M_1\ M_2]\left[\matrix{-B_3\\I}\right]=0$.

Combining all together we get
$$
[L_1\ L_2]=[M_1\ M_2]\left[\matrix{B_1 & B_2\\0 & 0}\right]=
[M_1\ M_2]\left[\matrix{B_1 & B_2\\0 & 0}\right]+
\underbrace{[M_1\ M_2]\left[\matrix{0 & -B_3\\0 & I}\right]}_{=0}=
[M_1\ M_2]\underbrace{\left[\matrix{B_1 & *\\0 & I}\right]}_{\tilde B}.
$$
Finally, $B=P_2\tilde B P_1^{-1}$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $.$ in the method $1$?

Comment: @Hoping_VN Just visually easier to see the projector $AA^+$ that complements $I-AA^+$, and to follow the analogy with $Bx=Ax_V+x_N$ in Peter's answer.

Comment: Hi! It means that $A. AA^{+} = AAA^{+}$. If I understand correctly, then $B^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Hoping_VN Yes, it means $A^2A^+$. The inverse to $A^2A^+$ alone does not exist, but $B$ has another part too that makes it to be invertible.

Comment: @Hoping_VN Look at the Method 2: $A^2A^+$ corresponds to $J_A$ which is not invertible, but the part $I-AA^+$ adds identity to the zero block to make the whole thing to be invertible.

Comment: Sorry! But if I assume that $A^{+} = (A^{*}A)^{-1}A^{*}$, then $B= I + (A-I)A(A^{*}A)^{-1}A^{*}$. Using Sylvester's determinant, we achieve $det(B) = det(A)$. Then if $A$ is singular, then $B$ is singular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30825/discussion-between-hoping-vn-and-a-g).